# how to execute Js Script in Selenium Webdriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

This line code returns number of elements. 
`document.getElementsByClassName("entry entryWriteable");`-> returns 70 elements

I want to implement a loop so that, Below line of code will execute for all the element.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("entry entryWriteable")[i].value;
```

Can any one help me how to impliment in C# selenium ?

Comment: Do you want to get all elements value attribute result which has class name `entry entryWriteable`??

Answer (score 3):

In order to execute JS in selenium on C# you should use the next code:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor) Driver).ExecuteScript("your code"));
```

So you can execute any JS code you want.

The `ExecuteScript` returns `object` so probably you can typify it.

Answer (score 0):

Like Denis said, but if you need a return value of all values in entire element array, then try:

```
using OpenQa.Selenium.Webdriver.Extensions

driver.ExecuteJavascript<string>(`
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("entry entryWriteable");
string returnAllElementTexts = "";
for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {

    returnAllElementTexts += els[i] + "|";

}
return returnAllElementText;`);
```

This will return a pipe-delimited string of all values. Split on pipe from C#. Is that what you wanted? All text values from array of elements?